iOS 18 fix small bottom sheets? .Net Maui
Bottom Sheets appear smaller on iOS 18.I am currently working with .NET MAUI and using the The49 Maui Bottom Sheet for bottom sheet functionality.I found a solution in Swift to fix the issue where modal sheets appear smaller on iOS 18 :swift solution But I'm not sure how to apply this in .NET MAUI with The49 Maui.
Any guidance on how to translate this Swift solution into .NET MAUI would be appreciated!
